# Loading a new window from local files and accessing it's contents

Tags: file, background, window, local

I am setting up a local webpage which shows videos in a HTML5 video tag. I just want to be able to do database search from a PHP request and show the results from which I can click on and show the video I want. The problem I have is that hte videos load WAY faster when loading from a "file:///" link than from the "http://" link. Server works flawlessly when in "HTTP" mode but nothing works in "file:///" mode which is normal as PHP codes only execute on the server side when requested to the server.

I have spent my full day trying soo much stuff. I changed my server to accept CORS, I tried window.open, storing the reference in a variable, local or global but I lose this as soon as I get out of my javascript function. I tried window.open in a function which is called from another function but no matter what I do, the window reference gets lost as soon as I leave the functions, or once the functions have finished. Since my browser is used as my main browser, I do not want to disable the security arround CORS but since my webpage's link comes from "file:///" requesting to "HTTP" on the same computer, CORS blocks me and wants an HTTP request which I can't give.

I have done all the searching for retrieving information from another webpage but I am always stuck with the "same domain" problem. I tried AJAX HTTPRequest, I just have no more solution for this simple problem which finished way more complicated than expected. The initial problem was just my videos not loading fast enough in HTTP mode (The speed difference is extreme, for 10 min videos, I can wait 5-10 seconds to skip through it while as in FILE:/// urls, It's almost instant, no waiting. longer videos of 1h, I can wait up to 20 and 30 seconds while as in file:/// mode, almost instant.) and I had to learn all that Allow cross domains stuff which ended up with no success either. I figure that maybe a few other heads may have better ideas than mine now.

```
#In my httpd.conf file from Apache
DocumentRoot "e:/mainwebfolder"
Alias "/lp" "d:/whatever"

//////////////////////////////////////
// index.php file that does not contain PHP contents
// window.location.href: file://d:/whatever/index.php
//////////////////////////////////////
<head>
  <script src="html/servcom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<video id="vplayer" width="1280" height="720" controls></video>
<div id="search-form">
  <input id="srch" name="srch" type="text">
  &nbsp;<button class="bbut" onclick="ServInfo('search-results','http://127.0.0.1/lp/html/db.php','mode=s','search-form');">Search</button>
</div>
<div id='search-results'></div>

<script>
  var dplay = document.getElementById("vplayer");
ShowVideo('MyVideo.mp4');
  function ShowVideo (vidUrl) {
    dplay = document.getElementById("vplayer");
    dplay.src = vidUrl;
    dplay.load;
  }
</script>

//////////////////////////////////////
// Now this is in my javascript file servcom.js
//////////////////////////////////////
var win_ref = -1;

function ServInfo(pop_field_id,web_page,params="",form_id="",exec_string = "") {

  var sparams = params;
  var swpage = web_page;
  var eobj = document.getElementById(pop_field_id);
  var moreparams = "";

  // If we entered extra parameters including form fields,
  // add the the "&" before the form field list
  if (sparams != "") {moreparams = "&";}

  // Get form field values if a form id is specified
  if (form_id != "") {
    var efrm = document.getElementById(form_id);
    sparams += moreparams+GetDivFields(form_id);
  }

  // Add the question mark if there is any parameters to pass
  if (sparams != "") {
    sparams = "?"+sparams;
    // Add recieving objects reference
    sparams += "&srco="+pop_field_id;
  }

  // If HTML element to populate does not exist, exit
  if (typeof(eobj) == "!undefined" || eobj == null) {return;}

  win_ref = window.open(swpage+sparams,"_blank");
//////////////////////////////////////
// right here win_ref will never be available once the code from this function has been finished executing although the variable is global. The problem starts here.
//////////////////////////////////////

  // Execute a string if a user defined one
  if (exec_string != "") {eval(exec_string);}
}

// Build a parameter string with div fields of type text, hidden or password
function GetDivFields(div_id) {

  var ediv = document.getElementById(div_id);
  var elem = ediv.children;
  var retval = "";
  var ssep = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  if (elem[i].type == "text" || elem[i].type == "hidden" || elem[i].type == "password") {
    retval += ssep+elem[i].name+"="+pURL(elem[i].value);
    ssep = "&";
  }
  if (elem[i].type == "checkbox") {
    if (elem[i].checked == true) {
      retval += ssep+elem[i].name+"="+elem[i].value;
      ssep = "&";
    }
  }
}

return retval;

}
//////////////////////////////////////
// And this is a brief overview of my db.php page
//////////////////////////////////////
<?php // Search Database code ?>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<?php echo $search_results; ?>";
  // I actually want to retrieve the info from this div element once it has been populated from the initial page that called window.open for this page. BUT again. window.opener becomes empty once my initial window.open script finishes.
</script>
```

Access my newly loaded page's "output" div innerHTML OR loading videos through local HTTP as fast as "FILE:///".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fanally found a solution. Since this is for local and presentation use only, I could bypass some securities. Basically, doing what we would normally NOT do in a website but all this WITHOUT modifying your webserver config or touching any .htaccess file. Basically, no security restrictions, just a plain old hack that poses no security breaches for your browser or your server.

**To be noted:**

1. 2 different websites exist (so 2 different folders at very different locations), 1 for developpement and serious releases, one for internal and/or presentation purposes.
2. Every file is local abd inside the presentation folder.
3. No PHP code can be ran from a "file:///" link.
4. Access to the mysql database is done through PHP and server is on Apach24
5. Reading video locally from a "file:///" link are WAY faster than from an "http://" link
6. Searching needs to be done in MySQL database frm a "http://" link and results need to be displayed on a webpage opened from a "file:///" link.
7. No changes must be made in the Browser's configuration so disabling CORS is not a solution.
8. Bypassing cors with methods proposed by many site won't work because of security reasons or because CORS bypass does not accept "file:///" links

PHP can write files on the server which is where I decided to bypass CORS. Since XML requests through AJAX can be done on the same origin domain an thus, purely in javascript. If a file exists which contains no PHP code AND resides on the same domaine i/e "file:///", the contents can the be read wothout any problems.

So I simply do the following in my db.php file:

```
$s_mode = "";
$s_text = "";
$sres = "";

if (isset($_REQUEST["srch"])) {$s_text=$_REQUEST["srch"];}
if (isset($_REQUEST["mode"])) {$s_mode=$_REQUEST["mode"];}

if ($s_mode == "s") {
    $sres = SearchDB($s_text);
    WriteFile("D:/whatever/my_path/dbres.html",$sres);
}

// Writes the contents of the search in a specified file
function WriteFile($faddress,$fcontents) {
    $ifile = fopen($faddress,"w");
    fwrite($ifile,$fcontents);
    fclose($ifile);
}
```

Now using a normal AJAX request, I do 2 things. I opted to use an iframe with a "display:none" style to not bother seeing another tab openup.

1. Do the actual request which opens the "cross-doamin" link in the iframe WHICH executes my db.php code. I basically open "http://127.0.0.1/whatever/db.php?param1=data&parma2=data" inside my iframe.
2. Once my search is done and I have the results, my db.php will save an html file with the results as it's contents in my "file:///" direct location's path so: "D:/whatever/my_path/dbres.html".

I added a new function in my servcom.js. So my new file's contents looks like this:

```
// Show page info in another page element or window with parameters (for local use only)
function ServInfoLocal(dest_frame,web_page,params="",form_id="") {
    var sparams = params;
    var swpage = web_page;
    var iweb = document.getElementById(dest_frame);
    var moreparams = "";

    // If we entered extra parameters including form fields,
    // add the the "&" before the form field list
    if (sparams != "") {moreparams = "&";}

    // Get form field values if a form id is specified
    if (form_id != "") {
        var efrm = document.getElementById(form_id);
        sparams += moreparams+GetDivFields(form_id);
    }

    // If destination frame does not exist, exit
    if (typeof(iweb) == "!undefined" || iweb == null)   {return;}

    // Add the question mark if there is any parameters to pass
    if (sparams != "") {sparams = "?"+sparams;}

    // Show results in iframe
    iweb.src = swpage+sparams;

}

// AJAX simple HTTP GET request
function ServInfo(pop_field_id,web_page,params="",form_id="",append_data_to_output = "",exec_string = "",dont_show_results = "") {

    var sparams = params;
    var swpage = web_page;
    var eobj = document.getElementById(pop_field_id);
    var moreparams = "";

    // If we entered extra parameters including form fields,
    // add the the "&" before the form field list
    if (sparams != "") {moreparams = "&";}

    // Get form field values if a form id is specified
    if (form_id != "") {
        var efrm = document.getElementById(form_id);
        sparams += moreparams+GetDivFields(form_id);
    }

    // If HTML element to populate does not exist, exit
    if (typeof(eobj) == "!undefined" || eobj == null)   {return;}

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // IE6-
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Do not show any results if requested
            if (dont_show_results == "") {
                if (append_data_to_output == "y") {
                    document.getElementById(pop_field_id).innerHTML += this.responseText;
                }
                if (append_data_to_output == "") {
                    document.getElementById(pop_field_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            // Execute a string if a user defined one
            if (exec_string != "") {
                eval(exec_string);
            }
        }
    };
    // Add the question mark if there is any parameters to pass
    if (sparams != "") {swpage += "?";}

    xmlhttp.open("GET",swpage+sparams,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }

// Build a parameter string with div fields of type text, hidden or password
function GetDivFields(div_id) {

    var ediv = document.getElementById(div_id);
    var elem = ediv.children;
    var retval = "";
    var ssep = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].type == "text" || elem[i].type == "hidden" || elem[i].type == "password") {
            retval += ssep+elem[i].name+"="+pURL(elem[i].value);
            ssep = "&";
        }
        if (elem[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (elem[i].checked == true) {
                retval += ssep+elem[i].name+"="+elem[i].value;
                ssep = "&";
            }
        }
    }

    return retval;

}
```

Now, my dbres.html file will contain just the div elements and all the information I need to show up in my "file:///" page from which the search request came from. So I simply have this inside my page:

```
<div id="search-form" style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">
    <input id="srch" name="srch" type="text">
    &nbsp;<button class="bbut" onclick="ServInfoLocal('iweb','http://127.0.0.1/whatever/html/db.php','mode=s','search-form');">Search</button>
    <button class="bbut" onclick="ServInfo('search-results','dbres.html');">Click here</button>
</div>

<div id="search-results">Results here</div>

<iframe id="iweb" style="display:none;" src=""></iframe>
```

For now I have 2 buttons, one for the search and one to show the results from my newly created file. Now, I can show my local videos which will load in my video container with "file:///" source directly without passing through http. I'll make my results display automatic which I will be able to do myself from here on.

So, if someone on planet earth wants to be able to do cross-domain searches in a MySQL database from a local file ran directly from the Windows explorer, there's not too many solutions, actually, I found none so here is at least one for who would ever need this solution.

For the curious ones out there, my next step will be to loop my folder until my dbres file is present using another js function. Once my file has been fetched, call another php file which wil destroy the created file and I'll be ready for another database request from my webpage situated in a "file:///" location.